# Java Runtime exec not executing batch script

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

I have a batch file located at `C:\app\stuff\dostuff.bat` that does stuff to the file system based on the arguments you provide it with. When I open a command line, and run it like so, it works perfectly fine:

```
C:\app\stuff\dostuff.bat zombies
```

Like I said, this invocation works perfectly (and properly handles the `zombies` arg). However, I am now trying to drive the execution of `dostuff.bat` from inside a Java app like so:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\app\\stuff\\dostuff.bat zombies");
    process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
    logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
}
```

When I run this, I get no exceptions, but it is *clearly* not properly executing the batch script (I can tell this because the rest of the file system that the batch script touches doesn't get modified like it should).  **Am I invoking this incorrectly?** Do I need to do something with forking processes? How might I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as follows

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\app\\stuff\\dostuff.bat zombies");
```

Comment: Thanks @Rene Winkler (+1) however this causes an undesirable command prompt to open and then hang there after the batch file finishes executing. Any ideas as to how to fix  (it can't stay like that, as is!).

Comment: insert at the very end of your bat-file `exit`